# CSS display conflict with div/nav and an image

Tags: html, css

I have a logo image i want to show to the left of a nav bar all centered on the page using a set width and auto margins, however after i set the display to inline on the div the margins disappear. I'd just like a point in the right direction to keep my margins and display the image inline with my navigation menu, thanks!
css:

```
#headWrapper{
    width: 850px;
    height: 430px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:inline;
}
nav {
    width: 550px;
    float:right;
}
```

html

```
        <div id="headWrapper">
        <img src="images/Logo.png" id="logo">
            <nav>
              <ul>
....
```

Comment: Close the `img` tag `<img src="images/Logo.png" id="logo" />`

Comment: The image tag is fine.  It may not validate as XHTML, but it will still render properly.  What you need to change is the headWrapper cannot be display:inline, and still have "shape".  Set it to `inline-block`, or leave as `block`, depending on what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways to work around this. Background-image would be one of them.

HTML

```
 <div id="headWrapper">
  <nav>
  <span class="icon"></span>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#headWrapper {
    width: 850px;
    height: 430px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline;
}
nav {
    width: 550px;
    float: right;
}
.icon {
    background-image: url(filelocation);
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
```